# XSLT: How to copy Javascript code from xml to html, modifying some lines of it

Tags: html, xslt, svg, html5-canvas

I need to transform an SVG file to HTML5 canvas, through XSLT.
The problem is about Javascript.
In svg file I have a script tag with some code, like in this simple example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="transform.xsl"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
id="slot" width="320" height="245">

   <script type="application/javascript"><![CDATA[
        var test = 2;
        alert("This is a test!");
   ]]></script>

   <----here svg drawing tags--->

</svg>
```

I want to output to html the Javascript code modified in some parts, and add some new code, like this:

```
<html>
   <head>
   <title> SVG to HTML5!</title>

   <script type="application/javascript">
      var new_test;                 <---the new code--->

      var test = 4;                 <---this is the modified code from 
      alert("This is a new test!");                 svg file--->
   </script>
   </head> 
   <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Your example doesn't seem clear. What kind of modifications to the JavaScript code do you want to perform?

Comment: I need to change lines of code to others..for example:
   document.getElementById("x").firstChild.nodeValue=x;    to    
   document.getElementById("x").setAttribute('value', x);
So, if there is a way to address lines of code and change it to what I want, I solve the problem!

Comment: My knowledge of XSLT is a bit less than advanced, but I think this kind of text editing is very difficult if not impossible in XSLT. I might be wrong, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is possible to write (somewhat complicated) code that would perform individual line replacements/insertions/deletions, a much more easier approach is to replace the complete `script` element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pNewScript">
     <script type="application/javascript">
      var new_test;                

      var test = 4;                
      alert("This is a new test!");                 
   </script>
 </xsl:param>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="svg:script">
  <xsl:copy-of select="$pNewScript"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document** (corrected to well-formed):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
id="slot" width="320" height="245">

   <script type="application/javascript"><![CDATA[
        var test = 2;
        alert("This is a test!");
   ]]></script>

   <!-- here svg drawing tags -->

</svg>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
id="slot" width="320" height="245">
   <script xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" type="application/javascript">
      var new_test;                

      var test = 4;                
      alert("This is a new test!");                 
   </script><!-- here svg drawing tags -->
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you, by the way, if I could in a not too complex way, I would substitute dinamically the code..can you explain me how can I substitute a single line?

Comment: I think this is a topic for a new question that you can submit. Congratulations for succeeding in narrowing the subject and precision of your initial question. In the future, please, try to be as precise and specific as possible. Always provide complete and wellformed examples, that require no work in correcting/guessing by the responders. I guess (again) that you don't have XSLT 2.0 available. With XSLT 2.0 such line-number manipulations are quite trivial. With XSLT 1.0 you need to write a recursively called named template to navigate to the wanted line-numbered line.

Comment: Oh yes, I can use XSLT 2.0 if it can help me easily! I submitted another question! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952425/xml-to-html-xslt-copy-a-node-replacing-some-lines-and-adding-new-ones