# XML to HTML (XSLT): copy a node replacing some lines and adding new ones

Tags: html, xml, xslt, svg

I must copy a `<script>` node from xml to html, but I need to replace dinamically some lines of it, and also add new ones. So I need to search-and-replace strings while the entire node is copying.

XML example:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
id="slot" width="320" height="245">

   <script type="application/javascript"><![CDATA[
      var a = 2;
      var b = "abc";
      var c = new Array(0,0,0);
      alert("Input!");
   ]]></script>

   <!-- here svg drawing tags -->

</svg>
```

HTML output example:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Example!</title>

      <script type="application/javascript">
          var a = 2;                          <!---same as xml--->
          var b = "def";                      <!---modified--->
          var c = new Array(0,0,0);           <!---same as xml---> 
          alert("This is a new example!");    <!---modified---> 
          var new = "new var";                <!---new code--->             
      </script>
   </head> 
   <body>
   </body>
</html>
```

If it's much easy, I can use XTLS 2.0.
How can I do?

Comment: Is this being done on the client or on the server? If it is being done on the server, it might be much more straightforward to code an extension rather than do this in standard XSLT.

Comment: Unfortunately it's done on client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlns:my="my:my">
        <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

        <xsl:param name="pSrcEdits">
         <line num="2" act="del"/>
         <line num="4" act="rep"
               newLine="var c = new Array(1,1,1);"/>
         <line num="5" act="ins"
               newLine="/* Inserted comment */"/>
        </xsl:param>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
         <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
         </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="svg:script/text()">
  <xsl:variable name="vLines" select="tokenize(., '&#xD;?&#xA;')"/>

  <xsl:sequence select="my:editLines($vLines, $pSrcEdits/*)"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:function name="my:editLines" as="xs:string*">
  <xsl:param name="pLines" as="xs:string*"/>
  <xsl:param name="pCommands" as="element()*"/>

  <xsl:for-each select="$pLines">
   <xsl:variable name="vLineNum" as="xs:integer"
    select="position()"/>
   <xsl:variable name="vCommand"
     select="$pCommands[number(@num) eq  $vLineNum]"/>
   <xsl:sequence select="my:editSingle(., $vCommand)"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:function>

 <xsl:function name="my:editSingle" as="xs:string?">
  <xsl:param name="pLine" as="xs:string"/>
  <xsl:param name="pCommand" as="element()?"/>

  <xsl:sequence select=
  "if(not($pCommand))
     then concat($pLine, '&#xA;')
     else
      if($pCommand/@act eq 'del')
         then ()
         else
          if($pCommand/@act eq 'rep')
            then concat($pCommand/@newLine, '&#xA;')
            else (: 'ins' :)
              concat($pCommand/@newLine, '&#xA;', $pLine, '&#xA;')
  "/>

 </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
id="slot" width="320" height="245">

   <script type="application/javascript"><![CDATA[
      var a = 2;
      var b = "abc";
      var c = new Array(0,0,0);
      alert("Input!");
   ]]></script>

   <!-- here svg drawing tags -->

</svg>
```

**produces the wanted result** (all commands carried out and the script edited):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     id="slot"
     width="320"
     height="245">

   <script type="application/javascript">
       var b = "abc";
 var c = new Array(1,1,1);
 /* Inserted comment */
      alert("Input!");

</script>

   <!-- here svg drawing tags -->

</svg>
```